# Natural join query - SQL (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and I have the following problem:
Given the following relations from HR:

Employee(Eid, Ename, salary)

Project(Pid, Pname, requiredWorkers)

WorksOn(Eid, Pid)

I want to return the Eids of employees for which all projects on which they work have precisely the same name (given the fact that several projects may have the same name and yet different Pids). I want to only return employees who work on at least one project.

I'm trying this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Eid
FROM (Employee NATURAL JOIN WorksOn NATURAL JOIN Project) AS t1, (Employee NATURAL JOIN WorksOn NATURAL JOIN Project) AS t2
EXCEPT 
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Eid
FROM (Employee NATURAL JOIN WorksOn NATURAL JOIN Project) AS t1, (Employee NATURAL JOIN WorksOn NATURAL JOIN Project) AS t2
WHERE t1.Pname <> t2.Pname
ORDER BY t1.Eid ASC
```

without success. Everything I try gives me different errors.

Do you have any idea how can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: EXCEPT is a set operation so you dont need the `DISTINCT` on the two queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
select e.Eid, e.Ename
from
    Employee e
    inner join
    WorksOn using (Eid)
    inner join
    Project p using (Pid)
group by 1, 2
having count(distinct p.Pname) = 1
```